# iText html2pdf with authentication

Tags: java, itext, basic-authentication

For legal reasons we need to archive HTML pages as PDFs when a new version is published. The system is not relevant, but the process is done on an authoring system of a CMS. The problem here is that the pages are not anonymously accessible. Getting the HTML is easy using Apaches `HttpClient` with `CredentialsProvider`, but then the iText `HtmlConverter` tries to load the CSS from the same host (provided with the `ConverterProperties`. I didn't see any API method where I could provide any kind of authentication to this converter.

Example Code:

```
CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
provider.setCredentials(new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "admin"));
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.cutom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(AuthScope.ANY, provider).build();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet); OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);) {
    HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
    ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();
    props.setBaseUri(BASE_URI);
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(httpEntity.getContent(), out, props);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Did I miss something or is this not possible with html2pdf?

Answer (score 1):

former `iText` employee here.

`html2pdf` doesn't really care about **how** you get the HTML or its resources.
`html2pdf` promises to convert an HTML document (and resources) to a valid PDF.

Obtaining the HTML (and having to provide authentication to do so) is outside the scope of that project.

I would suggest you simply copy the files locally (just download them using the apache library you mentioned).

Then you can load the document using a library like `JSoup` and change the paths to the resources to reflect your local copy.